# Flutter How to make CupertinoFullScreenDialog?

Tags: flutter, flutter-cupertino

I want to compromise the iOS full screen dialog  [something like this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/156888/58836042-714b4a80-860c-11e9-9c2b-6614917abcc1.gif) in flutter, any suggestions or solutions?

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Here try this out this I think this is what you are looking for

```
//This should be one of the first lines in your build function
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Show Bottom Modal'),
                onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet(
                  isScrollControlled: true,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => Container(
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    height: size.height,
                  ),
                ),
              )
```

Let me know how this works for you